# Definition for a Lipschitz domain

Tags: general-topology, analysis, definition

I am trying to understand the definition for a Lipschitz boundary/domain, but the definitions in literature and Wikipedia seem somehow too complicated.

Here is my interpretation of the definition:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a domain. We say that $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain, if for every $x \in \partial \Omega $, there exist a rigid transformation $f\text{: }\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, a radius $r>0$ and a Lipschitz function $L \text{: }\mathbb{R}^{N-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $$ f(\Omega) \cap B(f(x), r) = \left\{ (y_1, \dots, y_{N-1}, y_N)\in \mathbb{R}^N : L(y_1, \dots, y_{N-1}) < y_N \right\} \cap B(f(x), r),$$ where $B(x, r)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

I wanted to avoid talking about rotating and relabeling coordinate axes. That's why I added the rigid transformation so that I can rotate the domain $\Omega$.

Does this definition seem accurate, or should it be improven somehow? Are there any simpler formulations for the definition?

In addition, I want to ask if this definition is different from saying that for every $ x \in \partial\Omega$, there exist a neighborhood $U \ni x$ and a Lipschitz function $L\text{: }\mathbb{R}^{N-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N} $ such that $L(\mathbb{R}^{N-1}) \cap U = \partial \Omega \cap U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first definition is correct. In my opinion it's equivalent to one I know. Your second definition is incorrect. Consider the set $\Omega = \{(x,y):y>\sqrt{|x|}\}$. It isn't Lipschitz domain. Consider now the function
$$
L(t)=\begin{cases}(t|t|,|t|);&|t|\leq 1, \\ (t,\sqrt {|t|});&|t|\geq 1.\end{cases}
$$
This function is Lipschitz and $L(\Bbb R)=\partial\Omega$. We see that the important fact is that $\partial \Omega$ is locally the **graph** of some Lipschitz function (and $\Omega$ is locally epigraph/hypograph of such function), not only an image of such function.

The graphs of two components of $L$ are seen on the picture (first component is blue, second is green).
[image]

Comment: Why does $\Omega$ fail to be a Lipschitz domain? Is it because $x \mapsto \sqrt{\vert x \vert}$ is not Lipschitz?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is the requirement $L(y_1, \dots y_{N-1}) < y_N$ crucial? Would it be enough to say that locally the boundary is a graph of some Lipschitz function $L: \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? That is, for every $x \in \partial \Omega$, there is a neighborhood $U \subset \partial \Omega$ and a Lipschitz function $L: \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $G(L) \cap U = \partial \Omega \cap U$, where $G(L)$ is the graph of $L$.

Comment: And I should still include the possibility of having to rotate the boundary so actually I should have written $f(G(L))\cap U = \partial \Omega \cap U$ for some rigid transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: This is an interesting question. You should consider the set $\{(x,y):y\neq 0\}$. The boundary is the graph of Lipschitz function but it isn't a Lipschitz domain. It isn't connected, though.

Comment: But the definition conserns only sets $\Omega$ which are domains (non-empty, connected, open)?